# Adding fullscreen / soundoff buttons - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I would like to know if I can add a fullscreen and a sound button (on/off) on a page where I'm using VideoJS.
Is it possible to do that with JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 video has no API for fullscreen. You can set mute by assigning `true` or `false` to the [`muted`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-muted) property.

Comment: well yes its not really full screen it's just a function that resize the video to be as big as the browser view is: there is an example on the videojs website http://videojs.com/